# Is it possible to connect to SQL server in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sql-server

Is it possible to connect to SQL server in iPhone?. I want to create a new application and i want to retrieve the data from SQL Server and displayed. Previously it created using ASP.NET and SQL Server. Now my client wants to display the datas which is retrieved in SQL server data base. But the database contains the huge amount of data. So is it possible to convert the SQL Server to SQLite.(But SQLite is a light weight components). How can i do that? Can i use Web services? or i will ask to server side and convert the XML file and then i will use XML Parsing. I have no idea about it?

Please Explain Me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't work on an iPhone app but i know that our guys that do use webservices that return pure xml with data, return that to the iphone and then parse that xml.

Comment: +1 Web services are the way to go. If you're using multiple frontends to the same database or server, you should encapsulate it in a friendly API for your frontends to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... You are actually wondering if you can connect your iPhone-application to a SQL-server directly? Are you insane?! If you do, you need to connect with host-, username-, password-, en db-name-parameters. When people 'hack your binary converting it back to the source-code (.m-files)' they can read these parameters and create a custom connection to your db-server.

So, what you need to do is create a few scripts that parse your DB-data and return it as xml-data, so hackers won't be able to loggin into your db-server.