# Is it possible to add a record to a Microsoft SQL Server table using an iOS app?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sql-server

I know that it is possible to retrieve data from a SQL Server table using webservices that return pure XML (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447793/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-sql-server-in-iphone)), but that will not allow me to add records to the table, right?

I am primarily a C# .NET programmer, but I have dealt a little with iOS development. Is there a way I can use some sort of iOS-equivalent to a TableAdapter to add records to the table? The app would be running on the same network the servers are connected to.

Comment: The webservice is a wrapper for the database connection. And if you write it, it is up to you what it can do. So you can write the webservice with c# and use you TableAdapter.

Comment: A webservice can insert data just as easily as it return values. Pass in whatever parameters you need for the procedure to do what you want it do and off you go.

Comment: I would use WCF and JSON endpoint. You can read and write to a database easily.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. I will do some research into developing a webservice. Do you think I would have problems with multiple devices connected to the webservice simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *deterministicFail*, *Sean Lange*, and *Adam* stated in the comments, it is possible using a web service.

If anyone else is looking for some information on this topic, I found an article that explains this process in more detail. [Click here](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm) to go to the article.

Thanks for the help, everyone.